# How to connect to multiple channels in SharePoint by using single azure logic app?

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I need help on below request . please help me out if any one has tweaked the same issue .

Issue : I am trying to connect SharePoint channels by using trigger: "When a file is created or modified (properties only)" from logic app . In SharePoint documents tab has multiple channels . But logic app is allowing only one channel link at a time . we want to connect all channels at a time by using single logic app .

Could you please help me on this issue.

As of now we have implemented multiple logic apps with respective channels .so it's getting keep on increasing. if tomorrow new channels is getting created as per the business request , then again we will have create new logic app for new channel .we are thinking it's not good solution . please help me out with single logic app for multiple channels

Thanks

I tried to create list ,which contains all channel links and fetching all links from list by using get lists property with recurrence scheduler and then used for each loop to fetch the link information .

I want to pass link(which is extracted from for each loop) as dynamically as site address for trigger : "When a file is created or modified (properties only)".

Answer (score 0):

You can use single logic app to connect multiple channels. I have created a logic app to connect multiple teams channel and get file content from the newly uploaded files or modified files from different teams channels in share point.

- Created a logic app as shown below,
  [image]
- Given site address as https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/Mainsitename.
- Given Documents folder as Library Name as shown in above picture.
- In Get file content action, getting the content of uploaded or modified file using unique identifier as shown below,
  [image]
- This will get file content of all uploaded or modified file from the channels under the site name.
- I have uploaded one file in two channels which are under same site name and able to get content from the file uploaded in two channels.
- Logic app triggered as shown below,
  Run history for the file uploaded in test1 channel,
  [image]

Run history for the file uploaded in sample channel,
[image]

Comment: Hi Vijaya , 

Thanks for your time and Answered my question . 

It is not working for private channels .Which we have an access . 

The channels you have mentioned in the link as 'Teams' . But in our case link has 'Sites' .
https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/Mainsitename.

Thanks